# How can I tell if something is an event based on its signature?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I recently assumed that because the name of a function occurred nowhere in the codebase other than its definition, it must be dead code. I later found out it was actually an event, and therefore not dead. Its name and signature was `Private Sub lstFooWeekly_Change()`. Now that I know about [the `Change()` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change), it's pretty obvious that this code wasn't dead. In future, I'd like to be able to spot events ahead of time.

My question is this: Given the signature of something that looks like a function, how can I tell if it's an event?

Note: I'm a total VBA novice. I've tried searching the documentation for any answer to my question, but all that I've found is documentation for specific events. It seems that the general pattern is "if it's `Private Sub` and has `_` in its name, then it's an event", but I can't trust that without an official source. Furthermore, I'd much prefer an "if and only if" solution to my "if" guess. If what I'm looking for is documented anywhere, I'd appreciate a link.

Comment: Events do have a `_` in their name, but not all subroutines that have `_` are event handlers (e.g. users who write in snake_case, like `Sub Foo_Bar_Baz`, which is an excellent reason *not* to use snake_case).

Comment: To be safe, only trust the documentation and the VBA Object browser where applicable.

Comment: @KostasK. Can the object browser help here? I'm rather ignorant of it.

Comment: Yes it can. It lists the properties, methods and events of (almost) all objects. Not too much info, but you can see what's going on.

Comment: @KostasK. I've just had a look. I'm not seeing anything that plainly tells me that the event in question is an event.

Comment: They have different icons - the events have a thunder icon (if i say it correctly). So you can see the signature of the event e.g. `Event Change(Target As Range)`

Comment: This is a very silly question. If you have code that you intend to use, just STUDY it. There are very few shortcuts in life.

Comment: _The class that raises an event is the event source, and the classes that implement the event are the sinks. An event source can have multiple sinks for the events it generates. When the class raises the event, that event is fired on every class that has elected to sink events for that instance of the object._ If you only talk about the "sink" you do not have the complete picture.

Comment: The answer to the question as asked is simple: you can't. ;) In the main code window you should see the object in the left hand dropdown and the event name in the right hand one.

Comment: Let's not forget OnAction-routines for shapes (and Form-Controls).

Comment: @Rory And how do I tell what's an event from that window?

Comment: If you click in a routine and an object is selected in the left dropdown and a procedure in the right hand dropdown, it's an event.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this "dummy" example helps to clarify. Let's create two classes

**clsRaise**

```
Public Event Dummy()

Public Sub raiseDummy()
    RaiseEvent Dummy
End Sub
```

**clsSink**

```
Public WithEvents my As clsRaise

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set my = New clsRaise
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    my.raiseDummy
End Sub

Sub my_dummy()
    MsgBox "Oh no Risen from the code"
End Sub
```

Just step through the code by pressing F8 instead of F5 and watch

```
Sub TestDummy()
    Dim mD As clsSink
    Set mD = New clsSink
End Sub
```

Also have a look at the object browser for the VBA project and you will see that in the `clsRaise` you have the event `Dummy` and in the class `clsSink` you have  the sub `my_dummy` which implements the event. The rule for the naming of this sub is `<variable name>_<eventname>`. As you can also name  any procedure with an underscore you cannot really tell just by the name if a procedure implements an event.

[image]

[image]

Further [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/event-statement). Hope this makes sense

Comment: Rather than clear up my confusion, I think this answer proves that I'm confused. But that's a good thing. When I say "event", I'm talking about the `Private Sub Class_[foo]` examples. Do they have a specific name or a way to detect only them? Your screenshot proves that the object browser doesn't help.